# C# add user to Active Directory using Directory Services, Enabled property not working

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm using C# to create new active directory accounts on the fly, like this:

```
        public static void CreateUser(string userName, string password){
            UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(ContextType.Domain);
            user.SetPassword(password);
            user.Name = userName;
            user.SamAccountName = userName;
            user.UserPrincipalName = userName;
            user.Enabled = true;
            user.Save();
        }
```

The trouble is, the `user.Enabled = true;` line doesn't appear to do anything.  The account is created successfully, but I still have to manually go into the account using AD explorer and set it to enabled.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: I should add that I suspect that there may be a group policy setting or registry setting keeping that line from doing it's job.  I just don't know for sure.

Comment: Set the password, `Save()`, then set the account to Enabled and `Save()` once more

Comment: Thanks, but that does not appear to make the difference.

Comment: Actually, I take that back.  It works if `Save()` is called mmeadiately after setting to enabled, with nothing else in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for a user account to be `Enabled` in Active Directory, it must have a password. Set the password and create the account object first, then enable it subsequently:

```
public static void CreateUser(string userName, string password){
    UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(ContextType.Domain);
    user.SetPassword(password);
    user.Name = userName;
    user.SamAccountName = userName;
    user.UserPrincipalName = userName;
    user.Save();

    // Now that the account has been created and has a password, you can enable it
    user.Enabled = true;
    user.Save();
}
```